# Make jenkins build as FAILURE

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to mark whole build as FAILURE if tests return FAILURE or UNSTABLE. I thought that it would be enough to do this:

```
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
```

And it almost works. In jenkins console I can see

```
Finished: FAILURE
```

and whole pipeline is marked with red color, but when I move my mouse over it, it says that the status is SUCCESS:

[image]

I want to have an information that the status is FAILURE, not SUCCESS.
Below you can check my code:

```
stage('Run tests') {
    boolean currentBuildUnstable = false
    parallel("Test 1": {
        def result = build job: 'test-1-job', propagate: false
        currentBuildUnstable = currentBuildUnstable || isUnstable(result)
    },"Test 2": {
        def result = build job: 'test-2-job', propagate: false
        currentBuildUnstable = currentBuildUnstable || isUnstable(result)
    },
        failFast: true
    )

    if(currentBuildUnstable) {
        node('master') {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: why are you passing `propagate: false`? you're disabling the default behavior of marking the job as failed if a sub job fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to deal with this problem. I created additional stage in which I'm making build as FAILURE. My code now looks like this:

```
boolean currentBuildUnstable = false
stage('Run tests') {
    parallel("Test 1": {
        def result = build job: 'test-1-job', propagate: false
        currentBuildUnstable = currentBuildUnstable || isUnstable(result)
    },"Test 2": {
        def result = build job: 'test-2-job', propagate: false
        currentBuildUnstable = currentBuildUnstable || isUnstable(result)
    },
        failFast: true
    )
}

if(currentBuildUnstable) {
    stage('Check') {
        node('master') {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
    }
}
```

But, I don't know, why previous code haven't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that "Success" when hovered over is saying that stage was a success, not that the build was a success. If you'd like to force a stage to fail, just throw an exception. If you'd like to force a stage to always succeed, surround the stage's contents with a try/catch on any error.